# Python Boto3: Failed to fetch s3 file

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

Thanks in advance. I'm trying to fetch amazon s3 file after uploading it. But Client error occurs:

> *** botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found

My code:

```py
filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_bucket = current_app.config['S3_BUCKET']
s3_dir = current_app.config['S3_DIR']
client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=current_app.config['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'],
    aws_secret_access_key=current_app.config['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS'],
    region_name='us-west-1',
)

response = client.put_object(
    ACL='public-read',
    Bucket=s3_bucket,
    Key=f'{s3_dir}/{filename}',
    Body = io.BufferedReader(file).read(),
)

## response
## {'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'XXXXX', 'HostId': 'XXXXXXX', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amz-id-2': 'XXXXXXXX', 'x-amz-request-id': '19B2124B56C007AA', 'date': 'Wed, 11 Dec 2019 06:38:48 GMT', 'etag': '"XXXXXXXXXXXX"', 'content-length': '0', 'server': 'AmazonS3'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}, 'ETag': '"XXXXXXXXXXX"'}

image_file = s3.meta.client.download_file(s3_bucket, filename, f'{s3_dir}/{filename}')
# Client error occurs
```

I have walked through with [download_file](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file).

Comment: Do you have "s3_dir" directory in your local system where you want to download the file

Comment: Yeah, I've done eventually.

Comment: It is very clear from the Error , 404 - The file/object/key you are trying to perform GET is not present. Make sure you are doing GET with correct key

Answer (score 0):

I have set up `url file` directly.

added:
**app/config.py**

```py
S3_URL = 'https://xxxxxxxxx.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/uploads/'
```

from:

```py
image_file = s3.meta.client.download_file(s3_bucket, filename, f'{s3_dir}/{filename}')
```

to:

```py
image_url = s3_url + filename
```